# Is there any reason or advantage to specify string column length in BigQuery?

Tags: types, google-bigquery, sqldatatypes

I am new to BQ and experienced in OLTP RDBMS, I found the data in BQ for my company are mostly in `STRING` type while it was `VARCHAR(255)` or even less in the OLTP DB.

Is there any reason or advantage to specify string column length in BigQuery?

Comment: AFAIK, BigQuery does not have `VARCHAR` !

Comment: Yes but it has string with length to specify

Comment: BigQuery started to support it since Nov, 2021. Personally I don't see any advantage of it except it is a more cost-effective way of storing data.

Answer (score 2):

BigQuery does support parameterize data types: [reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#parameterized_data_types)

If you have a use-case in your business logic where length of string is used to do some validation of data then you can always use strict parameter for defining that column.

Here is a sample:

```
CREATE TABLE `{YOUR_TEST_TABLE_NAME}`
(
 val STRING(8)
)

insert into `{YOUR_TEST_TABLE_NAME}` (val) values ('abcdedfhij')
```

Above insert will fail as length is more than 8.